# Ubuntu Software search can't find any useful software I search for

Tags: software-center, 16.10

The new Ubuntu Software (on 16.10) can't seem to find any useful software I need to install. For example, if I search for any of the software listed below, I get "No Application Found".

- geany
- texlive-latex-extra
- qtcreator
- tlp

However, I can install all of them fine from the terminal via `sudo apt-get install`...

The discontinued Ubuntu software Center could locate all of these software fine. What is wrong with the new Ubuntu Software ?

Comment: Did you update after installing? That is a requirement (also was on older versions ;-) ) (`sudo apt update`)

Comment: @Rinzwind - But then why would `apt-get` work?

Comment: @Rinzwind - Yes, I did update.. several times.. and I have checked all of main, universe, restricted, multiverse from software & updates. I have changed my server to download from to Main Server from my country's server..

Comment: Then that is weird. It should find the software you mention there :P

Comment: Same here. The new software center is basically useless as it finds almost nothing.